# how to implement the "evasion" property in the "kick" method?

Tags: javascript

I want to implement the logic of the hero's evasion in the "kick" method.For the Hero a certain amount of the "evasion" property is set, on the basis of which its percentage of evasion depends, an example of the "evasion" archer is 0.6 that is 60 percent chance to evade the "kick".How to properly implement this logic and that the result of the message, display damage or evasion

```js
function Unit(maxHealth, basicDamage, evasion, type) {

    this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
    this.currentHeaalth = maxHealth;
    this.basicDamage = basicDamage;
    this.evasion = evasion;
    this.type = type;
    /*method for showing the status of life, true if the "health" is greater
     than 0 and false if equal to or lower */
    this.isAlive = function () {
        return this.currentHeaalth > 0
    };
    /* a method that
     shows the level of health*/
    this.getFormattedHealth = function () {
        return this.currentHeaalth + '/' + this.maxHealth + ' HP';
    };

    /*a method that returns the base damage of the heroand damage to the
     weapon (if it is set)*/
    this.getDamage = function () {
         return (this.weapon ? this.weapon.getDamage() : 0) + this.basicDamage;
    };
    /* The method of hitting
     the hero for the chosen purpose*/
    this.kick = function (target) {
            if (this.isAlive()) {
                target.currentHeaalth = Math.max(0, target.currentHeaalth - this.getDamage());
}
            return this;
    };
    /*method for showing all the characteristics of the hero and changes
     with them*/
    this.toString = function () {
        return "Type - " + this.type + ", is alive - " + this.isAlive() + ", " + this.getFormattedHealth() + ', hero current damage - ' + this.getDamage() + ' points' +
            ", hero evasion - " + this.evasion;
    }
}
function Archer(maxHealth, basicDamage, evasion) {
    Unit.apply(this, arguments);
    this.type = "archer";
}
var archer = new Archer(60, 5, 0.6);
function Swordsman(maxHealth, basicDamage, evasion) {
    Unit.apply(this, arguments);
    this.type = "swordsman";
}
var swordsman = new Swordsman(100, 10, 0.3)
while (archer.isAlive() && swordsman.isAlive()) {
    archer.kick(swordsman);
    swordsman.kick(archer);
}
console.log(archer.toString());
console.log(swordsman.toString());
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. In `if (this.isAlive()) {` within `kick`, the opening brace `{` has no matching closing brace `}`. You need to add one before the `return this` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function which fills an array with 10 digit of **0**s and **1**s according to evasion and return a random **1** or **0**:

```js
let evasion = 0.4,
  probability = function() {
  var notRandomNumbers = [],
    maxEvasion = 0;
  if ((evasion + '').split('.')[0] == 1 && (evasion + '').split('.')[1] == 0) {
    maxEvasion = 10;
  } else {
    maxEvasion = (evasion + '').split('.')[1];
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < maxEvasion; i++) {
    notRandomNumbers.push(1);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 10 - maxEvasion; i++) {
    notRandomNumbers.push(0);
  }
  var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * notRandomNumbers.length);
  return notRandomNumbers[idx];
}

console.log('1 )', probability());
console.log('2 )', probability());
console.log('3 )', probability());
console.log('4 )', probability());
```

Use it in `kick` function.

```
this.kick = function(target) {
  if (this.isAlive()) {
    target.currentHeaalth = Math.max(
      0,
      target.currentHeaalth - this.probability() * this.getDamage()
    );
  }
};
```

Full code will be this:

```js
function Unit(maxHealth, basicDamage, evasion, type) {
  this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
  this.currentHeaalth = maxHealth;
  this.basicDamage = basicDamage;
  this.evasion = evasion;
  this.type = type;

  /*method for showing the status of life, true if the "health" is greater
     than 0 and false if equal to or lower */
  this.isAlive = function() {
    return this.currentHeaalth > 0;
  };
  /* a method that
     shows the level of health*/
  this.getFormattedHealth = function() {
    return this.currentHeaalth + "/" + this.maxHealth + " HP";
  };

  this.probability = function() {
    var notRandomNumbers = [],
      maxEvasion = 0;
    if (
      (this.evasion + "").split(".")[0] == 1 &&
      (this.evasion + "").split(".")[1] == 0
    ) {
      maxEvasion = 10;
    } else {
      maxEvasion = (this.evasion + "").split(".")[1];
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < maxEvasion; i++) {
      notRandomNumbers.push(1);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 10 - maxEvasion; i++) {
      notRandomNumbers.push(0);
    }
    var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * notRandomNumbers.length);
    return notRandomNumbers[idx];
  };

  /*a method that returns the base damage of the heroand damage to the
     weapon (if it is set)*/
  this.getDamage = function() {
    return (this.weapon ? this.weapon.getDamage() : 0) + this.basicDamage;
  };
  /* The method of hitting
     the hero for the chosen purpose*/
  this.kick = function(target) {
    if (this.isAlive()) {
      target.currentHeaalth = Math.max(
        0,
        target.currentHeaalth - this.probability() * this.getDamage()
      );
    }
  };
  /*method for showing all the characteristics of the hero and changes
     with them*/
  this.toString = function() {
    return (
      "Type: " +
      this.type +
      ", is alive: " +
      this.isAlive() +
      ", " +
      this.getFormattedHealth() +
      ", hero current damage: " +
      this.getDamage() +
      " points" +
      ", hero evasion - " +
      this.evasion
    );
  };
}

function Archer(maxHealth, basicDamage, evasion) {
  Unit.apply(this, arguments);
  this.type = "archer";
}
var archer = new Archer(60, 5, 0.6);

function Swordsman(maxHealth, basicDamage, evasion) {
  Unit.apply(this, arguments);
  this.type = "swordsman";
}
var swordsman = new Swordsman(100, 10, 0.3);
while (archer.isAlive() && swordsman.isAlive()) {
  archer.kick(swordsman);
  swordsman.kick(archer);
}

console.log(archer.toString());
console.log(swordsman.toString());
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks, but how correctly to insert "console.log" about a miss and hit for inserting separately into methods "getDamage" and "probability" I output messages every time regardless of the result

Comment: What does `How correctly` means? Your "getDamage" function just return the damage of unit. log the value before returnin. In "probability", before the `return` statement log the "hit" or "missed" according to random value. @IgorShvets